# Removing XML Namespaces from XML Serialized Output

Tags: vb.net, xml-serialization

I am generating this XML using the serializer in VB.net as shown below

```
Dim string_writer As New StringWriter()
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(MyClass))
serializer.Serialize(string_writer, addr)
txttest.Text = string_writer.ToString()
```

though it is returning XML, I see xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ in all the elements, is there anyway I hide this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - just pass the default namespace you want to use to the constructor of your XmlSerializer:

```
Dim string_writer As New StringWriter()
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(MyClass), "")
serializer.Serialize(string_writer, addr)
txttest.Text = string_writer.ToString()
```

That should do the trick.